# My IDE is showing Salesforce IP Address as the Source IP in Login History

Tags: soap-api, login-history

Recently, I have noticed that when I login from Illuminated Cloud IDE using the standard connection (which is the SOAP connection with UserName\Password vs oAuth), I see two entries in the Login History from Other Apex API - one is my IP address, but the other is a Salesforce IP address. So even if I add my IP address to Network Access, I still need to add the security token to let me access the org.
Anyone know why this is happening? oAuth Connection seem to work ok, but that is often slower when I just need to access a sandbox for a quick fix\review metadata, so I still prefer to use the standard connection.

Comment: A specifically unhelpful comment: I haven't used username/password connection since switching to `sfdx` back in 2019. I haven't noticed any significant performance issue with "Authorize OAuth Org" connections. I do notice how slow it can be to refresh my global connections list, but that's probably because of my excessive use of scratch orgs  ;)

Comment: It might be better to address this to the [IC 2 Q&A group](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/g/qanda) - which I think you already did :D

Comment: For others, the thread is [here](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/g/qanda/c/Arld_ZWDAcI).

Comment: In my experience at least - for quickly setting up an new sandbox org and looking at something\making a quick update, the u/p method is much faster in terms of logging in, ,deploying etc. But also, I often tend to have a bunch of small projects on the go vs one org I am working all day. In those cases, oAuth works just as well.,

Comment: I think I am more curious\nervous that it has just started happening, isn't consistently happening, makes no sense, and suggests something weird is going on in the background - I don't like any of those things :)